# Javascript style.color doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById("myP").style.color);
}
```

```css
#myP {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="myP">This is an example paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Return text color of p</button>




</body>
</html>
```

If I do

```
<p id="myP" style="color: pink;">This is an example paragraph.</p>
```

It returns the color value correctly.

How can I get the color value if the value is set in css ?

I need Javascript not JQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Where are you linking your css with the html file? It appears there is no link between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
var element = document.getElementById('myP'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
alert(color);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wa0808tL/2/)